Is there a way to connect the react-native-app to flask?
I have a react-native app where I scan the qr code using expo and takes images from my mobile phone, this image is rendered in the app and send it to a flask endpoint, the data is sent but gives an error in the return of the backend function.
React-native:
const sendImageToServer = async (base64Image) => {
        const url = 'http://<ip address>:5000/predict';
        try {
            console.log("Sending image to server...");
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ image: base64Image })
            });
            const jsonResponse = await response.json();
            console.log("Response from server: ", jsonResponse);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error sending image to server: ", error);
        }
    };

    const captureFrame = async () => {
        if (cameraRef.current) {
            const photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync({
                quality: 0.5, // Reduce quality to decrease image size and increase upload speed
                base64: true,
            });
            setCurrentFrame(photo.uri); // Update the current frame
            sendImageToServer(photo.base64);
        }
    };

and flask code is:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import io

from ultralytics import YOLO


app = Flask(__name__)

# Load your model (adjust path and model loading as necessary)
model = YOLO('D:/CMP Year two/second semester/Advanced micro/Project/detector/dirt-debris/dirt-debris.pt')

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    
    title = request.json['title']
    body = request.json['body']
    print(body)
    return jsonify({"methods" : "1"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='ip address', port=5000)


I actually want the flask file to process the image and make classification and then send results back.
Any ideas?

Add the traceback to your question.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

we can't run your code, we can't see your computer, and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question (not in comments)
